# what is a good place to put a const in the following C++ statement

Tags: c++

Consider the following class member:

```
std::vector<sim_mob::Lane *>  IncomingLanes_;
```

the above container shall store the pointer to some if  my Lane objects. I don't want the subroutins using this variable as argument, to be able to modify Lane objects.
At the same time, I don't know where to put 'const' keyword that does not stop me from populating the container.

could you please help me with this?

thank you and regards
vahid

**Edit:**
Based on the answers i got so far(Many Thanks to them all) Suppose this sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Lane
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Lane(int h):a(h){}
    void setA(int a_)
    {
        a=a_;
    }
    void printLane()
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{

public:
    vector< Lane const  *> IncomingLanes;
    void addLane(Lane  *l)
    {
        IncomingLanes.push_back(l);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Lane l1(1);
    Lane l2(2);
    B b;
    b.addLane(&l1);
    b.addLane(&l2);
    b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->printLane();
    b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->setA(12);
    return 1;
}
```

What I meant was:

> b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->printLane()

should work on IncomingLanes with no problem   AND

> b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->setA(12)

should not be allowed.(In th above example none of the two mentioned methods work!)

Beside solving the problem, I am loking for good programming practice also. So if you think there is a solution to the above problem but in a bad way, plase let us all know.
Thaks agian

Comment: Just a wild guess... Have you tried `std::vector<const sim_mob::Lane *>`?

Comment: Do you want other parts of the code to be able to modify the stored `Lane` objects?

Comment: @Nick yes I do! only those parts of the code which use member container(IncomingLanes_) should not be allowed to change Lanes mentioned by it.

Comment: @rahman: I am quite amazed that none of the answers so far challenged the *pointers* requirement. Copying the original object make for much *simpler* and *safer* code. I would **sincerely** recommend a full copy.

Comment: @Matthieu: Making a full copy is not a solution, it's a hack. The solution is correct use of const (and maybe references if you really hate pointers that much).

Comment: @TonyK: I disagree. Pointer semantics are tricky, storing pointers expose you to all sorts of woes (will the object pointed to survive longer ?). I am a fan of the KISS principle: I'd rather challenge the assumptions first to make sure we don't need anything complicated before diving head first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
std::vector<const sim_mob::Lane *>  IncomingLanes_;
```

Or this way:

```
std::vector<sim_mob::Lane const *>  IncomingLanes_;
```

In `C/C++`, const *typename* * and *typename* const * are identical in meaning.

**Updated to address updated question:**

If really all you need to do is

```
b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->printLane()
```

then you just have to declare `printLane` like this:

```
void printLane() const // Tell compiler that printLane doesn't change this
  {
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: please refer to my question update. As I mentioned above, with your solution, there will be a problem accessing the elements

Answer (score 3):

A detour first: Use a smart pointer such `shared_ptr` and not raw pointers within your container. This would make your life a lot easy down the line.

Typically, what you are looking for is called design-const i.e. functions which do not modify their arguments. This, you achieve, by passing arguments via `const-reference`. Also, if it is a member function make the function `const` (i.e. `this` becomes `const` within the scope of this function and thus you cannot use `this` to write to the members).

Without knowing more about your class it would be difficult to advise you to use a container of `const-reference`s to lanes. That would make inserting `lane` objects difficult -- a one-time affair, possible only via initializer lists in the ctor(s).

A few must reads:

- The whole of [FAQ 18](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)
- Sutter on [const-correctness](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice98.htm)

Edit: code sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std; I'd rather type the 5 characters

// This is almost redundant under the current circumstance
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
//using namespace std; I'd rather type the 5 characters

// This is almost redundant under the current circumstance
class Lane
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Lane(int h):a(h){}
    void setA(int a_) // do you need this?
    {
        a=a_;
    }
    void printLane() const // design-const
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{    
    // be consistent with namespace qualification
    std::vector< Lane const * > IncomingLanes; // don't expose impl. details
 public:
    void addLane(Lane const& l) // who's responsible for freeing `l'?
    {
        IncomingLanes.push_back(&l); // would change
    }
    void printLane(size_t index) const
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG 
        IncomingLanes.at( index )->printLane();
#else
        IncomingLanes[ index ]->printLane();
#endif
    }        
};

int main()
{
    Lane l1(1);
    Lane l2(2);
    B b;
    b.addLane(l1);
    b.addLane(l2);
    //b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->printLane(); // this is bad
    //b.IncomingLanes.at(1)->setA(12); // this is bad
    b.printLane(1);

    return 1;
}
```

Also, as Matthieu M. suggested:

> shared ownership is more complicated because it becomes difficult to
>   tell who really owns the object and when it will be released (and
>   that's on top of the performance overhead). So unique_ptr should be
>   the default choice, and shared_ptr a last resort.

Note that `unique_ptr`s may require you to move them using `std::move`. I am updating the example to use `pointer to const Lane` (a simpler interface to get started with).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gave a sample in the question update. could you now help me out more with it?

Comment: @dirkgently: I would advise **against** `shared_ptr` in the general case. `unique_ptr` is *much* better. Or here... no pointer at all.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Any particular reason? This is a collection and at some point or the other he will have to `clear` the objects. A smart pointer is just the tool for the job. I can understand if you have reservations about the extra memory footprint for `shared_ptr`s though. Yes, `unique_ptr` too is a good choice.

Comment: @dirkgently: shared ownership is more complicated because it becomes difficult to tell who really owns the object and when it will be released (and that's on top of the performance overhead). So `unique_ptr` should be the default choice, and `shared_ptr` a last resort.

Comment: @dirkgently Thanks dude, Kinda embarrassing, but could you please give me the command to compile the above program? I used gcc -std=c++0x const.cpp but frenzy of errors.

Comment: @rahman: Check my edit. @Matthieu M.: `unique_ptr`s will probably also required `std::move` -- I'll update the code with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want the object to be able to modify the elements (i.e., you don't want the elements to truly be `const`).  Instead, you want nonmember functions to only get read-only access to the `std::vector` (i.e., you want to prohibit changes from outside the object).

As such, I wouldn't put `const` anywhere on `IncomingLanes_`.  Instead, I would expose `IncomingLanes_` as a pair of `std::vector<sim_mob::Lane *>::const_iterator`s (through methods called something like `GetIncomingLanesBegin()` and `GetIncomingLanesEnd()`).

Comment: "I don't want the subroutins using this variable as argument, to be able to modify *Lane objects*."

Comment: @Max Lybbert  but I need IncomingLanes_'s co-member methods to access IncomingLanes_ elements directly(only not to be able to change the elements)

Comment: @rahman: you have a fundamental problem that whatever you put in a `std::vector` must be either copyable or movable.  You can't make a `std::vector` or references, or a `std::vector` of `const int`s, for example.  You're going to go insane trying to get the right kind of `const` pointers in `IncomingLanes_`.  Even if (some or all) of the class's methods will interact with `IncomingLanes_` as read-only data, I would still recommend leaving the elements read-write, and having the methods that read the elements do so through `const_iterator`s.

Answer (score 1):

you may declare it like:

```
std::vector<const sim_mob::Lane *>  IncomingLanes_;
```

you will be able to add, or remove item from array, but you want be able to change item see bellow

```
   IncomingLanes_.push_back(someLine); // Ok
   IncomingLanes_[0] = someLine; //error
   IncomingLanes_[0]->some_meber = someting; //error
   IncomingLanes_.erase(IncomingLanes_.end()); //OK
   IncomingLanes_[0]->nonConstMethod(); //error
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need a way to ,at least, reads some values stored in the object(I just want to ban other functions from modifying values).In your example, I need the last line to work(if it is a read only access). Could you look at the edited question?

Comment: You can read any member you want, just implement const getter, e.g. int Line::GetValue() const { return some_int_member }, and then you can call it on const pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want other routines to modify IncomingLanes, but you do want to be able to modify it yourself, just use `const` in the function declarations that you call.

Or if you don't have control over the functions, when they're external, don't give them access to IncomingLanes directly. Make IncomingLanes private and provide a const getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible without making the pointers stored in the vector const as well.

```
 const std::vector<sim_mob::Lane*> // means the vector is const, not the pointer within it
 std::vector<const sim_mob::Lane*> // means no one can modify the data pointed at.
```

At best, the second version does what you want but you will have this construct throughout your code where ever you do want to modify the data:

```
 const_cast<sim_mob::Lane*>(theVector[i])->non_const_method();
```

Have you considered a different class hierarchy where sim_mob::Lane's public interface is const and sim_mob::Really_Lane contains the non-const interfaces. Then users of the vector cannot be sure a "Lane" object is "real" without using dynamic_cast?

Answer (score 0):

Before we get to `const` goodness, you should first use **encapsulation**.

Do **not** expose the `vector` to the external world, and it will become *much* easier.

A weak (*) encapsulation here is sufficient:

```
class B {
public:
    std::vector<Lane> const& getIncomingLanes() const { return incomingLanes; }

    void addLane(Lane l) { incomlingLanes.push_back(l); }

private:
    std::vector<Lane> incomingLanes;
};
```

The above is simplissime, and yet achieves the goal:

- clients of the class cannot modify the `vector` itself
- clients of the class cannot modify the `vector` content (`Lane` instances)

and of course, the class can access the `vector` content fully and modify it at will.

Your new `main` routine becomes:

```
int main()
{
    Lane l1(1);
    Lane l2(2);
    B b;
    b.addLane(l1);
    b.addLane(l2);
    b.getIncomingLanes().at(1).printLane();
    b.getIncomingLanes().at(1).setA(12); // expected-error\
        // { passing ‘const Lane’ as ‘this’ argument of
        //   ‘void Lane::setA(int)’ discards qualifiers }
    return 1;
}
```

(*) This is *weak* in the sense that even though the attribute itself is not exposed, because we give a reference to it to the external world in practice clients are not really shielded.

Comment: Thanks, did you mean printLane should work and setA shouldn't(as I needed)? I executed your program and none of them worked!? Am I making any mistake? the error is generated for both function calls!

Comment: @rahman: I just realized there is a mistake in the definition of `printLane`, you should add a `const` qualifier to the method to inform the compiler that it does not modify the `Lane` object. Instead of reading `void printLane() { ... }` is should read `void printLane() const { ... }`.